# Correlation matrix: decline in correlation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, descriptive-statistics, correlation-matrix

I performed a correlation matrix with Python. The following variables were included `total_equity`,`net_income`,`ROE`,`total_assets` and `ROA`. ROE was calculated as: net income / total equity.

As expected, the correlation is above 0.80 for most of the correlation results except between the following pairs:

`net_income` & `ROE`: around 0.2

`net_income` & `ROA`: around 0.2

`ROE` & `ROA`: 0.5

I would expect these correlation to be at least 0.80 like the rest. It doesn't make any sense that the correlation is much lower, since e.g. `net_income` is used in the calculation for `ROE`. What caused the decline of correlation?

Comment: 1) Typological Error in data entry? 2) Wrong scaling? 3) Just an empirical finding?

Answer (score 0):

Relationship doesn't always suggest correlation. For example, $X$ and $Y$ can be highly correlated but ratio of them might be irrelevant in terms of variation, e.g. let $X=Y$, then, the correlation between $X$ and $X/Y=1$ will be $0$.